# How not to start invalid form - Bootstrap Forms

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, web-frontend

I am using the default validation of bootstrap, but it starts as invalid, would there be anything you can do to make the form only invalid after doing some action?

```html
<form [formGroup]="simuladorForm" class="was-validated">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-6">
                    <label for="empresa">Empresa<span> *</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control is-invalid" formControlName="empresa"
                        placeholder="Empresa LTDA" id="empresa" required>
                    <div *ngIf="simuladorForm.controls['empresa'].invalid && (simuladorForm.controls['empresa'].dirty || simuladorForm.controls['empresa'].touched)"
                        class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="simuladorForm.controls['empresa'].errors.required">
                            Empresa é obrigatório.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-6">
                    <label for="cnpj">CNPJ<span> *</span></label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control is-invalid" formControlName="cnpj" mask="00.000.000/0000-00"
                        placeholder="00.0000.000/0000-00" id="cnpj" required>
                    <div *ngIf="simuladorForm.controls['cnpj'].invalid && (simuladorForm.controls['cnpj'].dirty || simuladorForm.controls['cnpj'].touched)"
                        class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="simuladorForm.controls['cnpj'].errors.required">
                            CNPJ é obrigatório.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrk4kh check email

Comment: Well maybe it would work without `class="form-control is-invalid"` ...

Comment: This already happens in the code, I need that form does not start with these css classes ("x" inside the input, read input), but only when the user interacts with the field.

Comment: You have hard-coded the invalid class, remove it to remove the invalid state.

Comment: @Maryannah Removed but still starting as invalid

Comment: remove `was-validated` too.

Comment: And provide a [mcve] containing your typescript code, your html code, and a reproduction of the issue.

Comment: @Maryannah when I remove was-validated, It does not apply CSS ("x" and "check" correct, input with border read etc)

Comment: @EliemersonFonseca not my comment !

Comment: @Maryannah this link is example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-by9oqw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not manage that.

The border is there because of the bootstrap way of handling controls. If you look at the class :

[image]

As you can see, this is handled by Bootstrap and it says that if the control is invalid, then it checks it as invalid.

To remove that, you can remove the `required` from your control, and check the control valid state just before sending it. The issue then is that your control will have a green border because it's considered as valid.

So ... Don't use Bootstrap ?

Comment: The solution was not clear. I need my layout to have these "check" or "x" actions. If I remove bootstrap I won't be able to

Comment: Yes you will be able to, but it won't be done for you, that's the difference. And as explained, bootstrap relies on your control state rather than its classes (as you can see on the screenshot), so it means you have no solution other that overwriting bootstrap (or simply removing it)